# How to change locale in laravel route?

Tags: laravel, localization

I am working on **Laravel localization.** I have all done but facing issue. When I change language from dropdown page successfully transalated but **language in ROUTE not change.**

In **web.php** I have setup this,

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect(app()->getLocale());
});
Route::get('language/change', [LocalizationController::class, 'changeLanguage'])->name('changeLang');
Route::group(
    [
        'prefix' => '{locale}',
        'where' => ['locale' => '[a-zA-Z]{2}'],
        'middleware' => 'setlocale'
    ],function () {

    Route::get('/', [MainController::class, 'index'])->name('main.index');
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']], function () {
        //
    });
});
```

I have added below code in **Middleware**,

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    if (session()->has('locale')) {
        App::setLocale(session()->get('locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

In **view file** I have added this code,

```
<select class="form-control languageSelector">
        <option {{ session()->get('locale') == 'en' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="en"> <span style="font-weight: bolder !important">En</span></option>
        <option {{ session()->get('locale') == 'fr' ? 'selected' : '' }} value="fr"> <span style="font-weight: bolder !important">Fr</span></option>
</select>
$(document).ready(function(){
        var url = '{{ route('changeLang') }}';
        $('.languageSelector').change(function(){
            window.location.href = url + "?lang="+ $(this).val();
        });
    });
```

**when I select language french from dropdown in route always see EN.**

[image]

In Controller I have added,

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
{
    App::setLocale($request->lang);
    session()->put('locale', $request->lang);
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Stack overflow. I have solve it by using this technique,

```
public function changeLanguage(Request $request)
{
    App::setLocale($request->lang);
    session()->put('locale', $request->lang);

    $url = url()->previous();
    $route = app('router')
    ->getRoutes($url)
    ->match(app('request')->create($url))
    ->getName();
    return redirect()->route($route, ['locale' => $request->lang]);
}
```

Comment: Nice, but that wont work for routes that has more than one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

The better way to use the session for this purpose because its a cheap way to define URL with language code, and here is the best way you can use on anywhere. you can follow all instruction
web.php
kernal.php
middleware
at the end you wrote this line of code in controller?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p63eB.png

Comment: I am also using session.

Comment: I have also added this code facing same issue.